# How to execute mssql script directly from file with Golang

Tags: sql, sql-server, go

I have been looking around for the answer to the question above with no luck. Excuse me if it is a duplicate. So basically I am trying to execute a sql script directly from file but I keep on getting the  " Incorrect syntax near ''. " error

```
func AnotherDatabase() (sql.Result, error) {
     rc, err := os.Open("./myscript.sql")
     if err != nil {
        return nil,err
     }
     buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
     buf.ReadFrom(rc)
     contents := buf.String()

     db, err := sql.Open("mssql", "mydatabase")
     if err != nil {
       return nil,err
     }
     defer db.Close()

     res, err := db.Exec(contents)
     if err != nil {
       return nil,err
     }
    return res,nil
}
```

Comment: I get this error :     mssql: Incorrect syntax near ' '

Comment: At the very least, strings in Go should be double-quoted.

Comment: Hi Dmitry.  I am not sure which string you referring to but the sql file I am loading has strings with single quotes as required by mssql server.

Comment: I have just realized that the file I am loading might contain some special characters illegal to mssql ? but when I copy the contents and paste on sql server the scripts executes as expected. How would you go about eliminating these characters in this case

Comment: I'm referring to these string: `sql.Open('mssql', 'mydatabase')`. This snippet should look like `sql.Open("mssql", "mydatabase")`.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry. I have fixed that but the issue still stands. How do I eliminate illegal characters in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized the illegal character causing issues was probably an extended ASCII character so I used the below method to strip off unnecessary characters from the file contents :

```
func stripCtlAndExtFromBytes(str string) string {
  b := make([]byte, len(str))
  var bl int
  for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
    c := str[i]
    if c >= 32 && c < 127 {
      b[bl] = c
      bl++
     }
 }
 return string(b[:bl])
}
```

as stated here https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_control_codes_and_extended_characters_from_a_string#Go